# Hierarchical Primary Index in SQL Table

Tags: sql, database-design, primary-key, teradata

I would like to construct a sql table that identifies people using two fields A and B.  It is a hierarchical relationship, so the B's always belong to some kind of A.

When creating my table, should my primary index be on (A,B), or just on A?  I am using Teradata which distributes data across amps based on the primary index, so I would imagine if B1, B2, and B3 all belong to A1, and if I want them to be grouped together, then the primary index should be on A only.

Edit: earlier I mistakenly typed primary key, it should read primary index

Comment: If your table can contain rows (A1, B1), (A1, B2), (A1, B3) then A can not be primary key, because it must be unique

Comment: Can the primary **index** be different from primary **key** under Teradata? For example, could you have the primary index on `{A}` and still have the primary key on `{A, B}`?

Comment: A Primary key is a logical construct typically enforced by a unique index on a table. In Teradata the **primary index** does not have to enforce the **primary key** of the table. It can be unique or non-unique and is typically defined based on access path and/or join patterns of the table. So yes, @BrankoDimitrijevic you can have a PI that is define separately from the PK. You can enforce the PK in this instance with a unique secondary index.